# Using ArcGIS model to batch export set of layout view as JPEGs?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcpy, data-driven-pages, jpg

I have a large number of layout views I would like to export as JPEG maps using ArcMap 10.0.  The layout view is based upon a user defined grid.  Normally what I would do is manually select a grid, zoom to the selected grid and export the layout as a JPEG.  But in this case there are over 1000 to do.

Is it possible to write an ArcMap model that will allow me to Select a Grid (table record) and then Zoom to the selected grid and then export the JPEG, which I can run as a batch?

Using ModelBuilder I imagine I would need to add the "Select" tool and then associate that with a "zoom to selected" script.  This is the part I fall down at.  While I have a script that does this, I cannot associate it with my selected record.

My grid is a polygon feature dataset (either shapefile or gdb) - basically a user defined grid for a layout at a particular scale. I really just need to zoom to each grid, which will have a numeric label 1 - 1000, in a field called ID, then export the layout of that map grid.

Comment: This sounds like a use case for Data Driven Pages (DDP) but I think you should **edit** your question to explain your manual workflow more clearly.  For example, if your "grid" is a feature class then it may be suitable to use as the index layer of DDP.

Comment: @PolyGeo - DDP can't be exported to image formats unfortunately. Only to PDF.

Comment: @GISGe I *think* it can, but I better test.

Comment: @GISGe you can use `exportToJPEG` when looping over the `dataDrivenPages` in arcpy to export multiple images, if the mxd has been set up with the data driven pages correctly.

Comment: @Cindy Williams, yes you're right, never tried this. I' curious to see if  this works, I've encountered so many strange behaviours with DDP in arcpy. One example at the bottom of the [Data Driven Pages class page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/DataDrivenPages/00s300000030000000/)

Comment: Many thanks for the pointer to Data Driven Pages. This solves my problem completely. All I need to do is have the required two fields in my feature grid attribute table: Name and Sort. I can then export all my map layouts as PDF files in one go.

Comment: I'm going to remove the words "or PDF" from your question because we have all been working under the impression that JPG was a mandatory requirement.  Don't be concerned that I am doing that - it just keeps the answer(s) lined up with the question.

Comment: this only 32 bit ,can plz add 64 bit if possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had to do something very similar using some cobbled together python script:

```
>>> field_name = "name"
>>> mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT") 
... for i in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
...    mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = i
...    row = mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageRow
...    print row.getValue(field_name)
...    arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, r"C:\temp\XXXX" + row.getValue(field_name) + ".jpg", resolution = 400) 
... del mxd
```

Each jpeg is given the name of the area which DDP iterates through